# Angularjs uib modal unable to call the modal controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to open a modal from my controller. I want the modal to have it's own controller which I have specified in the $uibModal.open.

parentController.js

```
$uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        controller: 'ModalController',
        scope: $scope,
        backdrop:'static',
        keyboard: false,
        size: 'md'
    });
```

modalController.js

```
angular.module('fidoApp.import').controller('ModalController',['$scope', '$uibModalInstance',
function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
    $scope.label = "from ModalController";
}]);
```

modal.html

```
<div>
    {{label}}
</div>
```

app.js

```
var fidoApp = angular.module('fidoApp', [
'ngRoute',
'ui.bootstrap',
'ngResource',
'ngCookies',
'ngAnimate',
'checklist-model',
'restangular',
'fidoApp.import',
'fidoApp.login',
'fidoServices',
'taximportServices',
'utilServices',
'errorServices',
'financialInstitutionsFilter',
'authenticationService',
'userService'
```

]);

I get the following error when I run this in my browser:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ModalController' is not a function, got undefined
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: show your scripts and their order

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Thanks for your comment. It made me figure out that my ModalController script tag was below the ParentController script tag. I interchanged the order and it worked.

Comment: if you solved the problem, either add your own answer or delete the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Aleksey in the comment, my scripts order was wrong. The ModalController script tag was below the ParentController script tag. Due to this, the reference to the ModalController in ParentController was undefined.

I changed the order of the script tags and put ModalController script tag before the ParentController script tag and everything started working fine.